# How to change oxford_iiit_pet:3 dataset to my own dataset in training Image Segmentation model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have 2 sets of file naming as "mask" and "ori_img" that representing masking labeling annotation and original image respectively, and I want to use the dataset to replace the oxford_iiit_pet:3 in the following code, how should I do?

```
dataset, info = tfds.load('oxford_iiit_pet:3.*.*', with_info=True)

def normalize(input_image, input_mask):

    # Normalize the pixel range values between [0:1]
    img = tf.cast(input_image, dtype=tf.float32) / 255.0
    input_mask -= 1
    return img, input_mask

@tf.function
def load_train_ds(dataset):
    img = tf.image.resize(dataset['image'], 
                        size=(width, height))
    mask = tf.image.resize(dataset['segmentation_mask'],
                        size=(width, height))

    if tf.random.uniform(()) > 0.5:
        img = tf.image.flip_left_right(img)
        mask = tf.image.flip_left_right(mask)

    img, mask = normalize(img, mask)
    return img, mask

@tf.function
def load_test_ds(dataset):
    img = tf.image.resize(dataset['image'], 
                        size=(width, height))
    mask = tf.image.resize(dataset['segmentation_mask'], 
                        size=(width, height))

    img, mask = normalize(img, mask)
    return img, mask

TRAIN_LENGTH = info.splits['train'].num_examples

# Batch size is the number of examples used in one training example.
# It is mostly a power of 2
BATCH_SIZE = 64
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = TRAIN_LENGTH // BATCH_SIZE

# For VGG16 this is the input size
width, height = 224, 224

train = dataset['train'].map(
    load_train_ds, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test = dataset['test'].map(load_test_ds)

train_ds = train.cache().shuffle(BUFFER_SIZE).batch(BATCH_SIZE).repeat()
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
```